# Removing newlines inside <a> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to python and also BeautifulSoup. Recently, I tried to get extract every `<a>` tag from some HTML in a local file. Part of my code looks like this:

```py
with open(dir_path,encoding="utf-8_sig") as html_file:
     soup =BeautifulSoup(html_file,'html.parser')
tag = soup.find('a')
print(tag)
```

The output is look like this

```
<a class="cmp-image__link" data-cmp-hook-image="link" href="/">
<img alt="logo" class="cmp-image__image" data-cmp-hook-image="image" itemprop="contentUrl" src="//imagesource"/>
</a>
```

What I want to get is a string without newline inside the block of `<a>` tag

```
<a class="cmp-image__link" data-cmp-hook-image="link" href="/"><img alt="logo" class="cmp-image__image" data-cmp-hook-image="image" itemprop="contentUrl" src="//imagesource"/></a>
```

I tried using `.strip()` and `.replace()`, but it didnt work. Please help!

### Update answer

This actually work well in my case !!!
from @BrokenBenchmark

```py
tag = '''<a class="cmp-image__link" data-cmp-hook-image="link" href="/">
<img alt="logo" class="cmp-image__image" data-cmp-hook-image="image" itemprop="contentUrl" src="//imagesource"/>
</a>'''

result = tag.replace('\n', '')

print(result)
```

Comment: Can you also post the code of methods you tried?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're worried about this.  HTML doesn't care about whitespace or newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.strip()` won't work here, as it only removes leading or trailing whitespace.

`.replace()` will work here, but **you need to assign its return value**, as it doesn't modify the string in-place (because Python strings are immutable).

This:

```py
tag = '''<a class="cmp-image__link" data-cmp-hook-image="link" href="/">
<img alt="logo" class="cmp-image__image" data-cmp-hook-image="image" itemprop="contentUrl" src="//imagesource"/>
</a>'''

result = tag.replace('\n', '')

print(result)
```

produces the desired output.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked !! In my case I also need to convert variable ```tag``` into string variable